# primitive function involving logarithm, square integrability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I want to ask if the following function, which is given by an integration

$f(y):=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^y \frac{1}{x^{1/2}\log{x}}dx,$

is locally square integrable near $y=0$?

Or equivalently,

$\int_{0}^{1/100} \left(\frac{1}{y}\int_0^y \frac{1}{x^{1/2}\log{x}}dx\right)^2dy$

is finite or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can show that $|f(y)|\leq \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{y}|\log y|}$, and that $\int_0^{1/100}\frac{1}{y(\log y)^2}\,dy$ converges.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just about to rephrase the question.

Comment: @Shaoming If you are going to rephrase a question in a way that invalidates existing answer, it should be a new question.